# Python flask app running on Pythonanywhere not able to send whatsapp messages through ngrok and twilio

Tags: python-3.x, flask, twilio-api, ngrok

My ngrok tunnel web interface is http://127.0.0.1:4040. However, I am not able to open the interface as it says 127.0.0.1 refused to connect. So I am not able to get the webhook link from the interface to add to Twilio Sandbox. Hence my python flask app is not able to reply back to messages. The app is python code using flask. It replies to whatsapp messages through Twilio API using ngrok tunnel. The code works fine in my local computer. However I added the Forwarding Link "https://c664-54-226-131-176.ngrok-free.app" to Twilio sandbox and found that when a whatsapp message is sent to the app, in pythonanywhere I see the following:

### HTTP Requests

POST /twilio
However, the reply message is not shooted back. Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you clarify a little?  In particular, it would be useful to know exactly what the code that is running on PythonAnywhere is doing -- perhaps a code excerpt would help.

Answer (score 0):

PythonAnywhere blocks almost every ip address of requests going out for free tier users, and this is probably the case. Here is a [similar question](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/14657/) on their forums and the [whitelist of allowed websites](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/). Good luck!

Comment: both ngrok and twilio are listed in the list and also I am having a pid account on pythonanywhere. Please help with the issue.